React Native Expo Hot Reloading Doesn't Reload Source Code
I am new to React Native (RN) so I am trying to understand the RN development workflow. I have found the debug workflow to be very inconsistent and assume there is something I am doing wrong or don't understand.
I have created two RN application using the templates: (I've tried on Windows and Linux)

A default application with the Expo Router using: npx create-expo-app
A blank application without Expo Routing using: npx create-expo-app --template (then selecting Blank (Typescript))

Testing with the Expo Router:
I can run both Android and Web targets and they run as expected. Then I test a simple change to the source.

From the Expo menu I make sure I am in "Development Mode"
Make the change to the UI (Change: "Welcome" to "Welcome2")

Result:

The UI changes; however, the source file does not change! The only way to have the source file match the UI is to do a "reload".

Testing WITHOUT the Expo Router:
From what I have read the router is required. After getting the Web and Android targets to run/render I make the following changes:

npm install @expo/metro-runtime
Create a new entry file (e.g. AppEntry.js)

// `@expo/metro-runtime` MUST be the first import to ensure Fast Refresh works on web.
import "@expo/metro-runtime";

import App from './App';
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";

registerRootComponent(App);


Modify the package.json main to be "main": "AppEntry.js"

Result:

This DOES work for the Web target only. Android is no better--I do have "Fast Refresh" enabled.

After more digging I found someone say that the Hot Reloading really only re-renders the UI and does not push file changes to the debugger--which might explain what I see. HOWERVER, then why would the Web target update both the UI and the source file in the debugger? Is there something I can do to enable Hot Reloading and/or Live Reloading in my project? I see people mention "settings" for this but I don't see anything for Web and only the "Fast Reload" for Android.
Any help would be much appreciated.
